# Cloud code not working

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

i am new at parse..trying code..trying to run a trigger required in my   project.but not able to track not even i am getting any error.
i am using cloud code i.e triggers...
what i want to do is, after update or save i want to run a trigger which will a column in a class with value of 200.

```
Parse.initialize('APPLICATION_ID', 'JAVASCRIPT_KEY');
    Parse.Cloud.afterSave("match_status", function(request) 
    {
        var query = new Parse.Query('Wallet');
        query.set("wallet_coines_number", 200);
        query.equalTo("objectId", "FrbLo6v5ux");
        query.save();
    });
```

i am using afterSave trigger in which match_status is my trigger name. after that i making a object called query of Wallet class. This object will set column 'wallet_coines_number' with the value 200 where objectId is FrbLo6v5ux. after that i used save function which will execute query.
Please guide me if i am wrong, or following wrong approach.

**Thank You !**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read the Parse [documentation](https://www.parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide) on Cloud Code ?

The first line of your code is only relevant when you are initialising Parse JavaScript SDK in a web page, you do not need to initialise anything in Parse cloud code in the `main.js` file. Also you cannot use a query to save/update an object. A query is for searching/finding objects, when you want to save or update an object you need to create a `Parse.Object` and save that.

So you code should become something like:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("match_status", function(request) {
    var wallet = new Parse.Object('Wallet');
    wallet.set("wallet_coines_number", 200);
    wallet.set("objectId", "FrbLo6v5ux");
    wallet.save();
});
```

Comment: can i send push notification with the afterSave trigger?

Comment: Certainly, you can send Push notifications in any of the triggers